# Remove punctuation and spaces from String

Tags: javascript

The function `compress()` would accept a sentence and return a string with all the blanks and punctuation removed. 
This function must call `isWhiteSpace()` and `isPunct()`.

I've already done the functions to call, but I don't know what's missing from my js code to make it call the functions.

```
function compress(sent) {
    var punc = "; : . , ? ! - '' "" () {}";
    var space = " ";
    if (punc.test(param)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
    if (space.test(param)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
    isWhiteSpace(x);
    isPunct(x);
}
```

Comment: `punc` should be a regex, or your test should be a `.includes`, not a `.test`. Also, your code will never pass the first `if/else` pair because they cover 100% of possibilities.

Comment: You can't put speech marks directly into a variable. You need to escape them by using a \. So var punc = "; : . , ? ! - \' \" () {}";`

Comment: Your function compress doesn't actually compress anything... All it does is return weather it contains punctuation.

Comment: Also, what is `param`? You haven't defined it...

Comment: You function will not get here `if (space.test(param))` because is returning `true` or 'false` above.

Answer (score 5):

> This function must call isWhiteSpace() and isPunct().

So you already have two functions which I assume return `true` when the passed character is either whitespace or a punctuation mark. Then you need not and should not duplicate this functionality by implementing a duplicate regex based text for whitespace and punctuation in your code. Keep it DRY - don't repeat yourself.

A `compress` function based on these two functions would look as follows:

```js
function isWhiteSpace(char) {
  return " \t\n".includes(char);
}

function isPunct(char) {
  return ";:.,?!-'\"(){}".includes(char);
}

function compress(string) {
    return string
      .split("")
      .filter(char => !isWhiteSpace(char) && !isPunct(char))
      .join("");
}

console.log(compress("Hi! How are you?"));
```

I agree that a regex test would probably the to-go choice in a real world scenario:

```
function compress(string) {
  return string.match(/\w/g).join("");
}
```

However, you specifically asked for a solution which calls `isWhiteSpace` and `isPunct`.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) to design the `isPunct` function.

```
function isPunct(x) {
    // list of punctuation from the original question above
    var punc = ";:.,?!-'\"(){}";

    // if `x` is not found in `punc` this `x` is not punctuation
    if(punc.indexOf(x) === -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Solving `isWhiteSpace` is easier.

```
function isWhiteSpace(x) {
    if(x === ' ') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can put it all together with a loop that checks every character in a string using [`String.charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt):

```
function compress(sent) {

    // a temp string
    var compressed = '';

    // check every character in the `sent` string
    for(var i = 0; i < sent.length; i++) {
        var letter = sent.charAt(i);

        // add non punctuation and whitespace characters to `compressed` string
        if(isPunct(letter) === false && isWhiteSpace(letter) === false) {
            compressed += letter;
        }
    }

    // return the temp string which has no punctuation or whitespace
    return compressed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return something in a function, execution will stop.

From what I can see, your function doesn't need to return anything... So you should just do this

```
function compress(sent) { 
    var punc = ";:.,?!-'\"(){} ";
    var array = punc.split("");
    for (x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        sent = sent.replace(array[x], "");
    }
    isWhiteSpace(x); 
    isPunct(x);
    return sent;
}
```